# The Browser Is Not Updating My CSS File When I'm Using XAMPP

Tags: css, visual-studio, browser, xampp

I'm Working On a New Project But When I'm Using XAMPP The Browser Doesn't Update My CSS File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a version number to the css link like the folowing :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?ver=1.1/>
```

Comment: FYI, this is called `Cache Busting`, and is done on all static assets like javascript files as well.